# GitLab TortoiseGit PuTTYgen --> but still need username/password

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I work with Gitlab and TortoiseGit. I created a PUTTYgen - then i managed the "push / origin / manage. (here i changed the name of URL)

[image]

All the time i do a commit/pull/push --> i need to type in my username and password.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be? Thank you very much.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use *SSH URL* if you want key authentication.

Like

```
git@gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab-ee.git
```

instead of

```
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee.git
```

You can either authorize with ssh (using key) or via HTTPS using login/password.